# TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/password_reset/. What is the solution?

Tags: django

This is my urlconf( taken from the Django docs)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
 url(r'^admin/password_reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', name='admin_password_reset'),
(r'^admin/password_reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
(r'^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
(r'^reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
)
```

This is the error:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'uidb64': 'NTA4MjY0NmZhOWQ3MTk1MDYzMGQyODgy', 'token': '3bv-abcb4fa27b0efa207808'}' not found.
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the difference is in the query keys:

```
<uidb36>
```

is what your url regex is expecting

but your page is sending

```
'uidb64'
```